# Why did these bones go all funky?

Tags: rigging, bones

I opened my blender project today and for some reason certain bones of the armature are scaled weirdly and are out of place. The model still moves correctly, but this just seems weird. Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm a blender newbie.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could select the bones that are over the others, or
interfering and send them to a second layer. Select the bones you want and press M, then in layer click the one you want to send them.